# Configuring Visual & Installer in VS 2022 for x64

Tags: inno-setup, visual-studio-2022, visual-and-installer

My config screen:

[image]

Why is it that I can't select **x64** in the list? In the **Alarm Clock** row there is **Add** / **Edit** in the drop-down list. But not for **AlarmClockSetup**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting step by step tutorial because *Configuration* in Visual Studio works differently than in Inno Setup:

Lets **assume** user wants to build **2 installers**: for 32 and 64 bit OS (two separate setup.exe-s).

Define **2 Visual Studio Configuration(s)** for this using standard Visual Studio Configuration manager dialog, choose any names for them you wish, I chose: "setup32" and "setup64", the result will look like this:

[image: setup64 configuration]

[image: Configuration Manager]

For **EACH** configuration define some symbol (called **conf** in this example) in Project Properties like this: **`conf=$(Configuration)`**

It is important to have this symbol set for EACH configuration

And now double check whether you have defined this symbol for EACH configuration

[image: Project Properties]

If symbol is not defined for some Configuration you receive "Error on line XXX: Undeclared identifier: conf."

Inno script to test the configuration:

```
[Setup]
AppName=InnoSetupProject1
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\InnoSetupProject1
DefaultGroupName=InnoSetupProject1
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\InnoSetupProject1.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Output
OutputBaseFilename=InnoSetupProject1
PrivilegesRequired=lowest

[Files]
Source: "Script.iss"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\InnoSetupProject1"; Filename: "{app}\InnoSetupProject1.exe"

[Code]

// Place your code here...   

procedure InitializeWIzard();
begin
    MsgBox(ExpandConstant('Configuration: {#conf}'), mbinformation,mb_ok);

#if conf == "setup32"
    MsgBox('This is setup32', mbinformation,mb_ok);
#endif

#if conf == "setup64"
    MsgBox('This is setup64', mbinformation,mb_ok);
#endif
end;
```

How it works:

When you choose "setup32" in Configuration dropdown, the `$(Configuration)` MSBuild variable is initialized and set to "setup32".

This `$(Configuration)` is mapped to Symbol **`conf`** (defined in Project Properties) that can be used anywhere in the script.

Use it for conditioning the setup behaviour using pre-processor `#if`, for Pascal code or anywhere as **`{#conf}`**.

So when the configuration is set to **setup32** and you build the script, the Inno pre-processor excludes the inappropriate parts from the script and only the correct message box is shown.

Use the **`#if`** for include/exclude files in your script, for `[Setup]` section directives, for defining the `Output` directory or anything, choose the Configuration and rebuild the setup.

[image: IDE]